# cant get angular to initiate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i was using plnkr to code the angular app im working on but when i try to code it locally everything angular seems to stop responding.

heres my html : i tried using angulars cdn and linking the actual file but nothing works.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='store'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
   <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
      <h1> {{store.product.name}}</h1>
      <h2> ${{store.product.price}}</h2>
      <p> {{store.product.description}}</p>
     <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="enter name">
     hello, {{yourName}}
      <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase"> add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
(function() { // code via app.js
  var app = angular.module('store', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.product = gem;
  });

  var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .',
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut:true,
  };

})();
```

Comment: where are you loading the angular js library?

Comment: Did you check networks tab (of browser you are using) and verified whether JS files are getting loaded?

Comment: @COOOL its in my JS folder.

Comment: @CuriousMind i checked the console and i had no errors , when using the cdn i get an error

Comment: what is app.js? and why do you have script below the </html> tag with no script tag wrapped around it?

Comment: @COOOL app.js is where i have my controller for the app im using, im following a tut on codeschool. and that code under the html is just a copy and paste code from my app.js file.

Comment: But you have some loose code at the end of your document all that script just hanging there after the </html> tag and with no <script> tags around it, this is likely the issue...

Comment: @COOOL sorry for the confusion , but that loose code is just the code from my app.js file that i copied to show here on stack. its not actually in my index file.

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure your call to the angular library resource is working -- or the path is correct. Double check within your developer console. Below is a version via google CDN and simple implementation -- also check out the 'starting your app with angular tut' it's useful! If you have errors in your console, update your question!*

angular js on cdn: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>`

```
<!doctype html><!-- sample only -->
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <h1>Hello, {{ yourName }}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Good [tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html). <-- read

---

Also, this could be just a problem initiating within your online IDE. There is a [guide](https://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) to initiating within using *JSfiddle*.net so you may want to check out the rules or guide for doing with *plnkr*.

Comment: @cool its weird , i added that cdn to my index and it still didnt work. But when i copied that code into my index only it worked.

Comment: then there's something wrong with your code -- likely at the end there.

Comment: the thing is that it worked on plnkr but when i use the same code on local files it doesnt work

Comment: then your JS isnt running locally; can you try it on a live enviroment?

Comment: how would i go about doing that?